# Perl die() call mysteriously not dying

Tags: perl, eval, die

I was able to get to this short code after doing some serious debugging at work with a very obscure bug in the project. A die call that was not dying.

The issue happens only when calling `script.pl`. If you call `Class_A` directly, then the `die` call will be successful.

We need three files:

**File 1: script.pl**

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use lib '.';
use Class_A;

# This should not execute. Class_A should die at loading time
print "We shouldn't get here. Class_A shoud not load and die.\n";
```

**File 2: Class_A.pm**

```perl
package Class_A;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Class_B;

# This code SHOULD die:
my $p = Class_B->new;
$p->do_something->die_now;


1;
```

**File 3: Class_B.pm**

```perl
package Class_B;
use strict;
use warnings;

sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    bless {}, $class;
}

sub do_something {
    my $self = shift;
}

sub die_now {
    die "No soup for you!";
}

sub DESTROY {
    eval {
        1;
    };
}

1;
```

Notice the chained call `at Class_A.pm line 8`? Well, if you unchain it, then the code dies successfully. :-|

```perl
# This works. There should be no difference.
$p->do_something;
$p->die_now;
```

And, the final surprise was to find out that **just by removing the eval call** `at Class_B.pm line 19`, then things work as expected and the script dies.

I had the opportunity to test this in `Perl 5.22.2`, `Perl 5.26.1` and `Perl 5.32.0`. For another wonderful surprise, this issue doesn't happen on `5.32.0` only.

Seriously, WT*? Any thoughts on what is going on here?

Comment: Interesting!  I am not sure the root cause, but the perldoc page on eval has this little statement: "It [eval] is also Perl's exception-trapping mechanism, where the die operator is used to raise exceptions.".  Seems the combination of Die+Destructor+Eval is getting confused.... like maybe something is up with the nesting of eval from Die with the eval in Destroy.

Comment: You forget mixing it with the chained call, because if not chained, then everything works well.

Comment: Tip: `.` is not the script's dir. Use `use FindBin qw( $RealBin ); use lib $RealBin;`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The code you posted doesn't exhibit the problem since 5.28.

The problem relates to `$@` getting clobbered (using `eval { }`) during the unwind that occurs due to an exception. Apparently, unsetting `$@` fools Perl into thinking no exception occurred.

According to perl528delta, `$@` is now set after everything is destroyed, which prevents the destructor from clobbering `$@`. You can also prevent the destructor from clobbering `$@` by adding `local $@;` (e.g. to support older versions of Perl).

Comment: Interesting. Any thoughts on why it happens with the chained call, but not by unchaining it? Eval is still doing the same thing at the same time.

Comment: Has to do with precisely when the variables on the stack are freed.